Proof that excessive function are also regular (super-harmonic)
In page 117 of Shiryaev's book optimal stopping rules, he claims that the excessive functions are also regular under some condition and state the proof is analogous to another proof, but I fail to come up with the full proof.
Let $\mathbb B$ be the aggregate of almost borel and lover $C_0$ continuous functions $g=g(x)$ given on $(E,\mathscr B)$ taking on values in $(-\infty,\infty]$ such that the process $g(X_t)$ is separable. Let $A^-$ denote the condition $\mathbb E_x(\sup_{t\geq 0}g^-(X_t))<\infty$. A function $f(x)\in \mathbb B$ is called excessive if $\mathbb E_x(f(X_t))\leq f(x).$  We want to prove that for an excessive function $f\in \mathbb B(A^-)$ and two Markov time with $\sigma\leq \tau$ almost surely, we have $\mathbb E_x(f(X_\tau)|\mathscr F_\sigma)\leq f(X_\sigma)$ and in particular $\mathbb E f(X_\tau)\leq \mathbb E f(X_\sigma)\leq f(x)$.
